# Raspberry Pico Pi cmake

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-pico

I have written a code for Pico Pi, and basically the program is about one LED and two buttons where one button turns on the LED and one turns it off. I am pretty new to raspberry and so I don't know much, I am using a virtual machine for cmake and make, but unfortunately, I can't turn my code into uf2, because I have not defined my link_gpio_get function in the sdlink.c file, which I don't know how to do so cmake is failing due to an undefined reference...

```
.EQU    LED_PIN1, 0
    .EQU    BUT_PIN1, 1
    .EQU    BUT_PIN2, 2
    .EQU    GPIO_IN, 0
    .EQU    GPIO_OUT, 1
.thumb_func
.global main
main:
    MOV R0, #LED_PIN1
    BL  gpio_init
    MOV R0, #LED_PIN1
    MOV R1, #GPIO_OUT
    BL  link_gpio_set_dir @ Initialize PIN1
    MOV R0, #BUT_PIN1
    BL  gpio_init
    MOV R0, #BUT_PIN1
    MOV R1, #GPIO_IN
    BL  link_gpio_set_dir
    MOV R0, #BUT_PIN2
    BL  gpio_init
    MOV R0, #BUT_PIN2
    MOV R1, #GPIO_IN
    BL  link_gpio_set_dir
wait_on:  
    MOV R0, #BUT_PIN1 @ Wait for turn on button
    BL link_gpio_get
    CMP R0, #1
    BEQ turn_on
    B   wait_on
turn_on:
    MOV R0, #LED_PIN1
    MOV R1, #1
    BL  link_gpio_put @ Turn on led
    B   wait_off
turn_off:
    MOV R0, #LED_PIN1
    MOV R1, #0
    BL  link_gpio_put @ Turn off led
    B   wait_on
wait_off:
    MOV R0, #BUT_PIN2 @ Wait for off
    BL link_gpio_get
    CMP R0, #1
    BEQ turn_off
    B wait_off
```

Here is my sdlink.c file

```
/* C wrapper functions for the RP2040 SDK
 * Incline functions gpio_set_dir and gpio_put.
 */
 
#include "hardware/gpio.h"

void link_gpio_set_dir(int pin, int dir)
{
    gpio_set_dir(pin, dir);
}

void link_gpio_put(int pin, int value)
{
        gpio_put(pin, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working to output uf2, using cmake on Windows 10 and I after watching a Youtube video, reviewing hackster and making my own edits I was able to get it working.

I'm not sure what OS you are using but hopefully these links and my edit can help guide you to identify the issue with your project.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUF9xjDtFfY

https://www.hackster.io/lawrence-wiznet-io/how-to-setup-raspberry-pi-pico-c-c-sdk-in-window10-f2b816

The following is my edit that allowed me to build and output I hope it helps!
After you've cloned the pico-examples project, navigate to the pico-examples directory. I opened pico_sdk_import.cmake in a text editor and I changed line 6 from if (DEFINED ENV{PICO_SDK_PATH} AND (NOT PICO_SDK_PATH)) to if (DEFINED ENV{PICO_SDK_PATH})

If you can provide a link to where you obtained the code you posted, maybe I can help further figure our what sdlink.c should contain.

Comment: Technified thanks.I wrote the code myself and found out on the web about get_gpio and link_get_gpio.Thought adding the function to the sdklink would be easy, I can attach 2 links I found regarding get_gpio function, there is a hint on the pico documentation and another link and it does sort of say how to add it to sdklink but having trouble understanding. I was told the pico_sdl_import.c shouldnt be modified. I coulndt output but for output you need 4 things: The program .S file, cmake file, sdklink  and the pico_sdk_import.c, the cmake and sdklink has to be edited to make it link to program

Comment: Feel free to add the links and I'll take a look to see if I can help.  Have you checked to make sure there isn't a typo and maybe it should be sdklink.c?  I don't see that you've included that in your code.  What exactly is the error you are getting?